# Best method to add style sheets into child theme?

Tags: child-theme

I created a Twenty Fifteen child theme and wondering what is the best
method to add style sheets into the child theme? Should I use enqueue script in `functions.php`, or add directly in `header.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, never add the stylesheet on `header.php` unless you have to. It is not the WordPress convention.

Secondly, adding stylesheet to `header.php` will cause certain problem like dependency hierarchy. Cause when you install any plugin and if it has its stylesheet then the dependency hierarchy is automatically managed by WordPress system by `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

Thirdly, by using `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook you can use WordPress default scripts and stylesheets which is kinda messy if you proceed to use it in the header.

Fourthly, (I'm not 100% sure) caching can be a problem if you use stylesheet on `header.php`.

And all those rule are applicable for themes as well as child themes and plugins.

Comment: If you think this answer clarified your concept, then it would be great if you accept the answer. @sam

Comment: sure, i am just reading the answer at the moment and just a small confusion left now , my HTML template have stylesheets linked in header sections which i have pasted into my header.php and added wp_head() below . So am i supposed to remove my stylesheets links from the header section and add it using enqueue script ? or am i not supposed to copy paste my HTML template header into my header.php which i want in all WordPress pages ?

Comment: Obviously you should add those scripts and stylesheets using enqueue script. Never put your scripts and stylesheet on any template or part of any template files unless you must have to.